# Linking for the second page (third I guess)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, hyperlink, viewcontroller

As the picture below I added a link for youtube in "First link" button, and on "Click" button, it goes to the second bag, now I don't know how to make another link the on the "Second link" button, can anyone help?

[image: picture]

Comment: I can't understand what you exactly want to do? Can you please elaborate a little more in your question?

Comment: you are opening a url on firstlink button and you want to open another url on secondlink button? right?

Comment: That's really simple. Have you created controller class for your secondViewController or you just drag dropped it in the storyboard?

Comment: Drag and drop :) I'm a newbie you know!

Comment: Let me find a tutorial for you.

Comment: Read this tutorial for help. [storyboard help](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Storyboards_in_Xcode_5) 
After this create a ViewController class for scene 2. Assign it that newly created class. Copy the same method you are having in your firstViewController. Attach it with the button. It will work for you

Comment: It's one page to another?

Comment: Okay, I made pages by linking them, I want to do a hyperlink (sorry for not mention this) in the second "another" page.

Comment: Oh, there you are, I wrote you a msg if you can see!

Comment: Want to do hyperlink means?

Comment: Actually it needs to be discussed on chat but you don't have enough points for chat. Question asked by you has ambiguities. Moreover large number of comments are discouraged.

Comment: Alright then, I don't have enough points to join, thank you :)